# Tricky Object Sorting and Removing from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have an array of objects (that contain a message), every object has the same structure. It has a message property which is an `NSDictionary`. One dictionary looks like this:

```
<message: {
    keyCreateDate = "06/08/14 21:23";
    keyMessage = Lorem ipsum;
    keyReceiverChannel = sampleString;
    keySenderUser = SampleName;
},...
```

My goal is to make an "inbox" where i would like to display the newest messages from every user in each cell. I want the show only the newest messages from each user, like the Fb messages, What'sApp or iMessage inbox, every cell in the table view represents the recent message from a friend. It looks very easy, but it's much harder than i imaged. So i need to remove every message from every friend, but always keep newest one. Actually i can remove all message from one user, but can't keep the newest while removing the others. Is it possible to do this?

I can remove all message for one specified user with this code:

```
    NSMutableArray *originalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:message];
    NSMutableArray *objectsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *cloneArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:originalArray];

    for (NMessage *messageObject in originalArray) {
        if ([messageObject.message[@"keySenderUser"] isEqual:usernameString]) {
            [objectsToRemove addObject:messageObject];
        }
    }

    if ([objectsToRemove count]>0) {
        [cloneArray removeObjectsInArray:objectsToRemove];
        NSLog(@"deleted: %@", objectsToRemove);
        self.messagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:cloneArray];
```

I think it would be the easier, if i could somehow add an exception to the `[cloneArray removeObjectsInArray:objectsToRemove];` line, that doesn't let to remove the newest ones. But it's also a problem that i need to sort the messages based on the `keySenderUser` before i delete them. My actual code can't do that, it can find only one pre-defined user's message and remove all of them. Please share with me if you have any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting the date form a database?

Comment: @Goppinath Yes. I include the date into the dictionary when the message was sent and i'm retrieving them here from the server.

Comment: Why don't you do everything in database level?

Comment: @Goppinath Because i can't access to it. I'm using  the PubNub history API and as i know it's not possible with it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel bottom up is better in your case where you build a new array which contains latest message dictionary.

The solution is as below.
1. sort the array using date.
2. Create a new list for holding user messages.
2. Loop through each object check whether the user is already present, If not add it to the created list.

The code solution is below, pass in your array of messaged, which would give a list of messages which are latest for an user.

```
-(NSArray *) GetLatestMessageListForEveryUser:(NSArray *) array
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate *obj1Date = [formatter dateFromString: [(NSDictionary *)obj1 objectForKey:@"keyCreateDate" ] ];
        NSDate *obj2Date = [formatter dateFromString:[(NSDictionary *)obj2 objectForKey:@"keyCreateDate" ] ];
        return  ([obj1Date earlierDate:obj2Date] == obj1Date);
    }];


    NSMutableArray *messageArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *usersArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *messageDictionary in sortedArray)
    {
        NSString *userName = [messageDictionary objectForKey:@"keySenderUser"];
        if (![usersArray containsObject:userName])
        {
            [usersArray addObject:userName];
            [messageArray addObject:messageDictionary];
        }
    }
    return messageArray;
}
```

Comment: Can i leave the `-(NSArray *) GetLatestMessageListForEveryUser:(NSArray *) array
{` line and change the array for the message array?

Comment: Yeah You can write the above code below this line of code, `NSMutableArray *originalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:message];'  use ordinalArray instead of array in the method.